# Ionic Virtual Scrolling Not Updating when new Item is pushed to Array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

hello actually am implementing virtuall scrolling in app
**Offers.html**

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="places">
          <ion-item-sliding *virtualItem="let place" #slideItem>

            <ion-item>

              <ion-label>{{place.title}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-item-sliding>


        </ion-virtual-scroll>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

**Offers.ts**

```
export class OffersPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  places = []
  testSub = new Subject
  constructor(private placeService: PlacesService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.places = this.placeService.getPlaces()
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.testSub.next({title : 'test'})
    },5000)

  }
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testSub.subscribe(data => {
      this.places.push(data)
    })
  }

}
```

here you can see i setup a new subject and after 5 sec it emit a new object and push it into **Places** array but problem is here that am not getting updated placesarray in virtualscroll help.!

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple just do this how @miloth has done , let me simplify the code for you

> Step 1

add an ID  `#listedLoadedPlacesScroll` like below line of code

```
   <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="places"  #listedLoadedPlacesScroll >
```

> Step 2

Get the reference of the ID in your .ts file like below line of code

@ViewChild('listedLoadedPlacesScroll') listedLoadedPlacesScroll: IonVirtualScroll;

> Step 3

then after doing your operation after here after pushing the items refresh it list by calling

```
 this.listedLoadedPlacesScroll.checkEnd();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into same issue, add an id to the ion-virtual-scroll

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="clients" #listedLoadedPlacesScroll approxFooterHeight="400px">
```

then call it on viewChild

```
@ViewChild('listedLoadedPlacesScroll') listedLoadedPlacesScroll: IonVirtualScroll;
```

make a subject in a service, and subcribe it on constructor

```
this.webService.updatedDataClients.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.listedLoadedPlacesScroll.checkEnd();
    })
```

thats pretty much it.

Comment: what you mean by `webService.updatedDataClients`

Comment: @MansourAlnasser you have to make a service, name it how you like it, i have named my service as WebService and the variable inside it is updatedDataClients = new Subject().